# Spring Sleuth trace/span IDs not available in HttpTraceRepository only if Mono response has body

Tags: java, spring-cloud, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-sleuth

I have logging in an Actuator [`HttpTraceRepository`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-http-tracing.html) bean which is invoked after a Mono response has been written. If the response has no body (only status) then I get the trace/span IDs in the log message. If however the response has a body, the log messages do not have the trace/span IDs **unless** they are handled by the same NIO thread that handled a "no body" request previously.

Here is a greatly simplified example that exposes the issue.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebClient webClient() {
        return WebClient.create();
    }
}

@Component
class AccessLoggingHttpTraceRepository implements HttpTraceRepository {

    @Override
    public List<HttpTrace> findAll() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(HttpTrace trace) {
        LogFactory.getLog("netty.Access").info("ACCESS");
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
class PublicationFamilyEndpoint {

    @Autowired
    private WebClient webClient;

    @GetMapping("/body")
    public Mono<String> testWithBody() {
        return callWebClient();
    }

    @GetMapping("/nobody")
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<Object>> testWithoutBody() {
        return callWebClient().map(s -> ResponseEntity.ok().build());
    }

    private Mono<String> callWebClient() { // doesn't matter what happens here - this is just an example of a reactive call
        return webClient.get().uri("http://example.com").retrieve().bodyToMono(String.class);
    }
}
```

When I call

```
curl -sS 'http://localhost:8080/test/nobody'
```

I get logs

```
[-,ff016a7a5a9aadbb,ff016a7a5a9aadbb,false] 5741 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] netty.Access: ACCESS
```

When I call

```
curl -sS 'http://localhost:8080/test/body'
```

I get logs

```
[-,,,] 5741 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] netty.Access: ACCESS
```

See however this series of request logs. The first two are to the `/nobody` endpoint and the rest are to the `/body` endpoint. If the `/body` request is handled by the same thread as a `/nobody` request previously, the trace/span IDs are present.

```
[-,78bbe5342dbcd517,78bbe5342dbcd517,false] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,941cc2e3afc9bbc4,941cc2e3afc9bbc4,false] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,,,] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,,,] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,5728dcc1559f64ae,5728dcc1559f64ae,false] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,,,] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,,,] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-1] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,,,] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,00241261eb9931bd,00241261eb9931bd,false] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] netty.Access: ACCESS
[-,,,] 7091 --- [ctor-http-nio-4] netty.Access: ACCESS
```

Is this a bug? Can I work around it in some way?

Versions: Spring Boot 2.0.4.RELEASE/2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT, Spring Cloud Finchley.SR1

Dependencies: spring-boot-starter-actuator, spring-boot-starter-webflux, spring-cloud-starter-sleuth

Comment: Can you check it with the latest `2.1.0` snapshots? The community has upgraded the reactive support. Most likely it's related to ordering of filters though. Maybe the HttpTrace filter is executed before the start of Sleuth's filter or after it's finished.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak The issue persists with Spring Boot 2.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. I have noticed that if the /body request is handled by the same NIO thread that handled a "no body" request previously, the trace ID is present. See update to the question.

Comment: Can you please file an issue in Sleuth so I don't forget? I'll have to take a closer look

Comment: Created https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1054